# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table x for entity type y

Tags: entity-framework-core

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational: Cannot use table x for entity type y since it is being used for entity type x and there is no relationship between the primary key of x and the primary key of y.

Comment: The question is resolved but is there a way to make two classes for the same table? For example one is for only main attributes, the other is for all attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case, I accidentally used the same name for 2 tables (TableAttribute) while defining the schema in the data layer. Fixing the naming fixed this issue.